# C# Reflection GetField().GetValue()

Tags: c#, reflection, getvalue

Given the following:

```js
List<T> someList;
```

Where T is a type of some class:

```js
public class Class1
{
  public int test1;
}

public class Class2
{
  public int test2;
}
```

How would you use Reflection to extract the values of test1/test2 stored in each List item? (The field names are provided)

**My Attempt:**

```js
print(someList[someIndex]
.GetType()
.GetField("test1")
.GetValue(someList) // this is the part I'm puzzled about. What kind of variable should i pass here?
```

**The Error I'm getting:**
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object", and according to microsoft docs the variable I should pass to GetValue is "The object whose field value will be returned." - which is what I'm doing.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Should be `.GetValue(someList[someIndex])`

Comment: [Documentation says:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getvalue?view=net-5.0#parameters) "`obj` Object: The object whose field value will be returned." in other words, the object you want to get the field of, similar to `obj.test1`, so yeah in this case `someList[someIndex]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add {get;set;} to your properties
`public int test1 { get; set; }`

```
var t = someList[0].GetType().GetProperty("test1").GetValue(someList[0], null);
```

I recommend you can use this method

```
public class Class1
{
    public int test1 { get; set; }
    public object this[string propertyName]
    {
        get { return this.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(this, null); }
        set { this.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).SetValue(this, value, null); }
    }
}

var value = someList[0]["test1"];
```